# Updating tableViewCells property after data change

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have an array of checklist items I am displaying in a tableViewController. Each item is contained in a tableViewCell and the background color of that cell changes from white to green when an item is checked. I can check and uncheck items and the cell's color changes as expected.

I added a reset button, to change all of the items to the unchecked state. I tested the reset function and the items are being reset however the tableViewCells are not updating to the correct color, they remain in their last state. I have tried using

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

and

```
tableView.reloadRows()
```

but this doesn't seem to have any effect on the cells.

My reset function located in the model:

```
func resetCheckedStatus(for items: [Item]) -> [Item] {
  var resetItems: [Item] = []

  for item in items {
      item.isChecked = false
      resetItems.append(item)
  }
  return resetItems
}
```

My reset action in the tableViewController

```
    @IBAction func resetItems(_ sender: Any) {

    let title = "Reset Items"
    let message = "Are you sure you want to reset all items to unchecked status?"

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: {action in self.items = resetCheckedStatus(for: self.items)} )
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    alert.addAction(okAction)

    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.tableView.reloadData()

    if let indexPaths = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows {
        tableView.reloadRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post your `cellForRow(at:)` method. My guess is that you're not fully configuring your cells after recycling them. Remember that a cell you dequeue can be left in the state it was in when it was last used, including changes to it's background color. You can't assume that it will be in it's default state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reload the table view after your items array is changed. Move reload table view code inside the handler block of okAction as follows

```
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK",  
                             style: .default, handler{action in
                            self.items = resetCheckedStatus(for: self.items)
                                         self.tableView.reloadData()} )
```

Comment: That did it!  Care to elaborate on why reloadData() needs to be called in the handler block as opposed to after?

Comment: The handler closure is called only after the ok button on your alert is tapped. A closure is a self contained block of functionality, although they appear inline they don't essentially execute in a sequential manner. So in your sample code the table view will reload even before your model object are modified by the resetCheckedStatus method.